# NumberFormatter::parseCurrency gives different results on machines with same PHP version

Tags: php, formatting, debian, icu, php-5.6

I have a machine  with Debian Jessie and PHP 5.6.9, and a machine with Debian Wheezy using the same PHP version (but from dotdeb.org).

The following piece of code gives different results on both machines:

```
$value = '900,00';
$cur = 'EUR';
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('nl_NL', \NumberFormatter::TYPE_CURRENCY);
$formatter->setPattern('#,##0.00;#,##0.00-');
$res = $formatter->parseCurrency($value, $cur);
var_dump($res);
var_dump($formatter->getErrorMessage());
```

Output for Debian Weezy:

```
float(900) string(12) "U_ZERO_ERROR"
```

Output for Debian Jessie:

```
bool(false) string(36) "Number parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR"
```

Both machines have php5-intl installed. Both machines have libicu installed (libicu48 on wheezy and libicu52 on Jessie). Both machines have the same locales available:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Also, I am unable to reproduce it on 3v4l.org. There I get a parse error on all PHP versions: http://3v4l.org/XgsBu

What's the problem here? Why are the results not consistent?

Comment: So check what locales the two boxes have installed (`locale -a`). The international formatter is dependent on the locales that are avaibale on the server

Comment: ...and you you might also want to look at the output of `if ( false===$res ) {
 echo $formatter->getErrorMessage();
}` after ->parseCurrency(). (But the locales are the first thing to look into)

Comment: Both machines have the same locales. Wheezy works but Jessie gives U_PARSE_ERROR. See my edits.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. The code I posted is buggy and should not have worked either way. The correct code is this:

```
$value = '900,00';
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('nl_NL', \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setPattern('#,##0.00;#,##0.00-');
$res = $formatter->parse($value, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_DOUBLE);
var_dump($res);
var_dump($formatter->getErrorMessage());
```

The bugs:

- The second constructor argument should not be one of the `TYPE_*` constants. Those are for the `parse` method.
- The currency parser expects a currency symbol. Since my value doesn't have one, I should use a `DECIMAL` parser instead.